# Special Array: An array is special if every even index contains an even number and every odd index contains an odd number

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, logical-operators

what is the problem of this code?
it's showing false. this should be true.

```
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        
        return ((arr[i % 2 == 0]) % 2 == 0) && ((arr[i % 2 !==0]) % 2 !== 0)
    }   
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])) // false??
```

Comment: Your `return` statement in the `for` loop means that your function will return after examining only the first element of the array; `return` exits the function immediately.

Comment: Any suggestion to make the loop worthy to examine each and every element ,  apart from every method of array ?

Comment: Use an `if` and `return false` on an invalid entry in the loop. After the loop `return true`.

Comment: You could do it in one line and save unnecessary loops if you use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every): `function isSpecial(arr) { return arr.every((item, index) => item % 2 === index % 2); }`

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code and avoid unnecessary looping as soon as the first element breaking the rule is found.

#### Using a `for` loop

```js
function isSpecial(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== i % 2) return false
  }
  return true;
}
```

#### Using `Array.prototype.every`

```js
function isSpecial(arr) {
  return arr.every((item, index) => item % 2 === index % 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `return ((arr[i % 2 == 0]) % 2 == 0) && ((arr[i % 2 !==0]) % 2 !== 0)` syntax is wrong. Hope the below function meets your requirement.

Logic

- Loop through the array, check each node for "special" condition and store it in `isNodeSpecial`
- "special" condition means, even index has even number and odd index have odd number.
- Initialize a variable outside the loop which holds the `isSpecial` status of array.
- Update the isSpecial varaible as logical and of `isSpecial` and `isNodeSpecial`.
- Whenever a single node violates the condition the `isSpecial` is set to false and loop exits.

```js
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
  let isSpecial = true;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length && isSpecial; i++) {
    const isNodeSpecial = (i % 2 === 0) ? arr[i] % 2 === 0 : arr[i] % 2 === 1;
    isSpecial = isSpecial && isNodeSpecial;
  }
  return isSpecial;
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])); // true
console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 10, 6, 1, 6, 3]));// false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if any element does not satisfy the condition and immediately return `false`. If all elements satisfy the condition, then return `true`. That is best solution when it comes to performance. You can change your code like this:

```js
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== i % 2) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])) //true
console.log(isSpecialArray([1, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])) //false
```

Comment: Why this overly complicated condition in the `if`? `if (i % 2 !== arr[i] % 2) return false`

Comment: You are totally right, let me simplify that. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is wrong because your code will return right after first execution of loop, the easiest thing you can do is to put an if condition inside your loop and check whether your odd index element is odd or even index element is even and return false if your element is wrong and keep checking for the whole array and return true outside the loop if array is special.

```
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(!((i%2==0 && arr[i]%2==0) || (i%2==1 && arr[i]%2==1))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[i % 2 == 0] //returns undefined, b/c you are trying to do arr[true]
undefined % 2 //returns NaN
NaN == 0 //returns false, so you always get false
```

It is also true what the others are saying about the loop breaking right away, but that is not the main problem.

Try this instead:

```
function isSpecial(element, index) {
    if(index%2 == 0) {
        return element%2 == 0
    }
    else {
        return element%2 != 0
    }
}
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
    return arr.every(isSpecial);
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])) // true
console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 4])) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do
direct way :

```js
const isSpecialArray = arr => arr.every((v,i)=>i%2===v%2)

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])) // true
console.log(isSpecialArray([1, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3])) // false
```

same idea with array.reduce():

```js
const isSpecialArray = arr =>
  arr.reduce((r,v,i)=>r && ((i%2) === (v%2)), true)

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 3]))
console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1, 6, 4]))
```

Comment: May I ask you whether there is any particular reason why you are suggesting `reduce()` over `every()`, please? To me, in this case `reduce()` seems less intuitive and readable. Thank you in advance for your answer. :)

Comment: @secan no, you won't find any "particular" reason for that. And do you have a particular reason for asking me to justify an answer that you obviously dislike?

Comment: I do not dislike your answer; I was just wondering whether there was any particular reason for it (e.g. performance) so I asked. I am a self-taught and pretty mediocre developer, with no formal CS education and a lot of knowledge gaps - especially for what concerns more theoretical topics -, therefore when I see a more experienced developer proposing a solution for which I cannot guess the reason, I ask in the hope of understanding better and maybe learning something. I did not mean to criticize or belittle you and I apologize if I gave this impression (English is not my native language).

Comment: @secan : [rank : 48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFI%27s_100_Years...100_Movie_Quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sweet and simple way to solve this(python)

```
        def is_special_array(list):
        res=[]
        for i in range(0,len(list),2):
            if (list[i]%2==0) and (list[i+1]%2!=0):
                res.append(True)
            else:
                res.append(False)
        return all(res)
```

Comment: the question is asking to address the issue in that particular solution posted by the author

Comment: answer does not address the question properly